# Why the mqtt connection over 1883 port to IBM Watson IoT Platform does not work?

Tags: iot, watson-iot

I've created a new Watson IoT Platform service but I can't connect devices to over port 1883 (following the documentation instructions).

Comment: following other forums I've found out that when you newly provision a Watson IoT Platform service, you need to use TLS by default (i.e., HTTPS). If you want to connect over 1833 port then you can revert your service to support non-TLS by changing the Connection Security settings in your organization.

You can change your service's security policy by going to Security > Connection Security and changing the default rule. "TLS Optional" will allow you to connect to 1883.

This change has been made because it ensures that Watson IoT Platform is secure out of the box.

Comment: As reference....these are the sources:

https://developer.ibm.com/iotplatform/2017/04/06/notification-changes-increased-default-security-via-tls-ibm-watson-iot-platform/

https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/06/watson-iot-platform-security-enhancement/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newly provisioned Watson IoT Platform services now mandate that devices connect over TLS (i.e., port 8883), rather than port 1883. You can change your service's security policy by going to Security > Connection Security and changing the default rule. "TLS Optional" will allow you to connect to 1883.

This change has been made because it ensures that Watson IoT Platform is secure out of the box: it is then a conscious decision by your administrator to lessen the security should you wish to connect to port 1883.